# Python searching lists with lists, all and any

Tags: python, list, if-statement, any

I am having trouble for some reason with a certain if statement. Let's say I have three lists:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
list2 = [1,2,4,5]
list3 = [4,5,6,7,8]
```

I evaluate each. I want to flag it if the list has both 4 AND 5, but does not have either 2 OR 3. I thought this would work:

```
if all(q in [4,5] for q in the_list_name) and not any(q in [2,3] for q in the_list_name)
```

I would expect this to flag only `list3`. However it returns false on all of the lists. I wonder what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The first clause tests whether every element is either 4 or 5, which is obviously not true of any of the examples.

Comment: your flag condition sounds wrong.  (includes 4 && 5) && !(includes 3 || 4) which simplifies to 4 && 5 && !3 && !4 would always return false, because it can never both include 4 and not include 4 at the same time

Comment: Would you like both 3 and 4 to be excluded or just one of them? List3 has both 4,5 and does not have 3, which is the same as in List2. So if you expect List3 to be flagged, why wouldn't List2 be flagged?

Comment: Darn, I tried to make a simple example and made a dumb mistake with the lists. The idea is merely that the first lists have either all or part of the second clause but all lists have the first clause. A better example could be 4 AND 5, but neither 2 OR 3. So all lists have 4 and 5, but only list3 has neither 2 or 3.

Comment: @ThomasNicholson the two lists being used can not have overlapping numbers, or it will always be false by definition.  You might want to edit your example?

Comment: @ThomasNicholson In that case, this should work: `{4, 5}.issubset(lst) and not {2, 3}.intersection(lst)`.

Comment: I edited the post with new example. @user120242 Yes, that was my stupid error while making the example. Should make more sense now.

Comment: @ekhumoro that's a lot more elegant than the current.  You should post it as an answer.

Comment: @ekhumoro thank you, great, that does it! love the simplicity

Answer (score 1):

If we look at `all(q in [4,5] for q in the_list_name)`, so only half of that if, we can see that it returns `False` for all the lists. That statement actually tests if all the elements in a list are either 4 or 5. Same for the other one, it tests if all the elements are 3 or 4, so it makes sense for all of them to be `False`.

To properly test if the list contains 4 and 5 but doesn't have 3 OR 4, you can change your code to:

```
inc = [4, 5]
exc = [2, 3]
testList = lambda l, inc, exc: all(i in l for i in inc) and not any(e in exc for e in l)
```

having the results:

```
>>> testList(list1, [4, 5], [2, 3])
False
>>> testList(list2, [4, 5], [2, 3])
False
>>> testList(list3, [4, 5], [2, 3])
True
```

Taking a closer look:

- `all(i in l for i in inc)`: all the elements from inc (elements that need to be included) are part of the given list l
- `not any(e in exc for e in l)`: for every element in the given list l, non of them should be in he exc list (elements that need to be excluded)

**Edit:**

If you want to use the @ekhumoro answers from the commends (that is more elegant) but also have parameters for elements that need to be included/excluded, you can use:

```
testList = lambda l, i, e: {*i}.issubset(l) and not {*e}.intersection(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach could be:-

`if ( (4 in _list_name and 5 in _list_name )and (2 not in _list_name or 3 not in _list_name))`